# Flask-SocketIO block my app

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io

I am trying to create a simple WebSocket connection. When I do the next code, my server receives the string "hey!" and the client receive the string "yo!", everything is fine at that point but when I click in other views the server freeze.

Code:

Client side:

html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="editor-page2">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port  + '/test');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('my event', {data: 'hey!'});
    });
    socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
      console.log('Received #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data);
    });
</script>
```

Server side:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask('flaskwp1')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/editor-page1')
def webprint():
    return render_template('editor-page1.html')

@app.route('/editor-page2')
def webprint2():
    return render_template('editor-page2.html')

@socketio.on('my event', namespace='/test')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
    print('received json: ' + str(json))
    emit('my response', {'data': 'yo!'})
```